# Virtualbox incoming connections are the same IP

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Okay, so I'm hosting a VPS for someone using Virtualbox. I've setup a server for that guy with a NAT network type ( this way I could port forward the entire thing so it can be used for what the guy wants ). The guy can use remote desktop to connect to the server, however. Everyone who tries to join his game, gets the same IP. I guess this has something to do with the guest settings, if I'm not mistaken.

Could anyone provide me any more information about the reason behind these IP's?

I'm running on the latest version of Virtualbox with a windows 7 enterprise 64bit version where a SA-MP server is being hosted on.
Everyone who connects to his server gets the ip; 10.0.2.2. Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If a machine is located behind NAT, then all of the incoming connection will always be recorded only from a single source, that is you router's IP. It's normal since all of the incoming connection will have to go to the router first.